# Creating new C# script in unity not being added in VS's solution

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Every time I create a new script in untiy and open it with VS, I can't seem to find it in its solution, unless I "Reimport All" in unity. This woudn't be a big deal if it managed to find the references to my other scripts and have an intellisense as well. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tt479x1t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem is. Wherever there's an error in any of the scripts no matter what error, unity is unable to sync any other scripts, including the one with the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think [UnityVS](http://unityvs.com/) will solve your issues